# in_array always returns false with fgetcsv

Tags: php, arrays

i'm doing a plugin for my wordpress site. in that i need to import contacts in csv file in "ID,Name,Mobile,Email,Age,Gender" format thus it will enter into the db automatically. the code i used is:

```
<?php global $wpdb;
$mainurl = get_option('siteurl')."/wp-admin/admin.php?page=add_admin_menu_import_contact";
if($_POST['importtrue'] == "true" ) {


    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );


    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['import_contact']['name'];
    $uploaded_file_type = $_FILES['import_contact']['type'];  
    $allowed_file_types = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel','text/plain');

    //$path= EMAIL_PLUGIN_DIR.'/import_contact/';

    if(in_array($uploaded_file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {

        // Options array for the wp_handle_upload function. 'test_upload' => false
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false ); 
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['import_contact'], $upload_overrides);

        $csv_titles = array( 'eemail_patient_id'    =>  array('ID', 'id'),
                            'eemail_name_sub'   =>  array('name', 'NAME','Name'),
                            'eemail_mobile_sub' =>  array('Mobile', 'phone','Phone','MOBILE'),
                            'eemail_email_sub'  =>  array('email', 'emailid','EMAIL','Email'),
                            'eemail_age_sub'    =>  array('Age', 'Old','AGE'),
                            'eemail_gender_sub' =>  array('Gender', 'gender','GENDER')      );
        if ( $movefile ) {
            echo "<span style='color:green'>File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.</span>\n";
            // var_dump( $movefile);               
            print_r($csv_titles);  echo '<br/>';

            if (($handle = fopen($movefile["file"], "r")) !== FALSE) 
            {

                $header = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

                $dbkey = array();

                foreach($header as $key) {
                    echo $key;
                    foreach ($csv_titles as $keys => $vals)
                    {
                        echo '<br/>'.$keys;
                        echo '<br/>';
                        print_r($vals);
                        if (in_array ($key,$vals))
                        {

                            $dbkey[]=$keys;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                }
                // echo '<br/>Dbkey: '; var_dump($dbkey);
                if(! empty($dbkey)) {
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
                    {
                        $i = 0;
                        $values = array();
                        foreach($dbkey as $key) {
                            if (!empty($data[$i])) {
                                $values[$key] = $data[$i];
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }

                        $keys = "`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($values)) . "`";
                        $values = "'" . implode("', '", $values) . "'";
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".WP_eemail_TABLE_SUB." ({$keys}) VALUES ({$values})";
                        $wpdb->get_results($sql);



                    }
                    $usql="update ".WP_eemail_TABLE_SUB." set patient_date= CURDATE() where patient_date='0000-00-00' ";
                    $wpdb->get_results($usql);
                }
                else { echo "<span style='color:red'>But provide valid titles for CSV in first row to import contacts </span>";}
                fclose($handle);
            }

            // unlink($movefile["file"]);
        }


    } else 
    {
        echo "Not an allowed type!\n";
    }



}
?>


    <script language="JavaScript" src="<?php echo emailnews_plugin_url('inc/setting.js'); ?>"></script>
    <form name="form_importcontact" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8"  method="post" action="admin.php?page=add_admin_menu_import_contact" onsubmit="return importcontact_submit()"  >
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td  align="left" valign="middle" width="10%">Select CSV File:</td>

                <td  align="left" valign="middle"><input name="import_contact" id="import_contact" type="file" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td height="35" colspan="2" align="left" valign="bottom">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%" align="left">
                                <input name="publish" lang="publish" class="button-primary" value="Import Contacts" type="submit" />
                                <input name="publish" lang="publish" class="button-primary" onclick="_cancel_import()" value="Cancel" type="button" />              
                            </td>
                            <td width="50%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr> <input type="hidden" id="importtrue" name="importtrue" />
                </table></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>

</div>
```

the output i always getting is:

> File is valid,and was successfully uploaded.But provide valid titles for CSV in first row to import contacts

when i output the arrays :

`$csv_titles: Array ( [eemail_patient_id] => Array ( [0] => ID [1] => id ) [eemail_name_sub] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => NAME [2] => Name ) [eemail_mobile_sub] => Array ( [0] => Mobile [1] => phone [2] => Phone [3] => MOBILE ) [eemail_email_sub] => Array ( [0] => email [1] => emailid [2] => EMAIL [3] => Email ) [eemail_age_sub] => Array ( [0] => Age [1] => Old [2] => AGE ) [eemail_gender_sub] => Array ( [0] => Gender [1] => gender [2] => GENDER ) )`

`$key: ID Name Mobile Email Age Gender`

output of `echo 'keys'.$keys` and  print_r($vals):

```
keys: eemail_patient_id
Array ( [0] => ID [1] => id )
keys: eemail_name_sub
Array ( [0] => name [1] => NAME [2] => Name )
keys: eemail_mobile_sub
Array ( [0] => Mobile [1] => phone [2] => Phone [3] => MOBILE )
keys: eemail_email_sub
Array ( [0] => email [1] => emailid [2] => EMAIL [3] => Email )
keys: eemail_age_sub
Array ( [0] => Age [1] => Old [2] => AGE )
keys: eemail_gender_sub
Array ( [0] => Gender [1] => gender [2] => GENDER )
```

i figured out that the **second `in_array`** if condition is not executing thus the #dbkey is empty. but i can't find out the reason why in_array is false always. logically it seems to be correct for me. please help me to find the reason?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try echoing the value of `$uploaded_file_type`

Comment: it returns "text/csv" . its the correct format sir.

Comment: then it has to work.....

Comment: ya..but the problem happens with the in_array. that if loop is not executed. can u please check that loop. i checked it so many times didn't find any logical error.

Comment: `in_array()` is working fine, else you would have not the output `File is valid, and was successfully uploaded`

Comment: https://eval.in/102591

Comment: if you are talking about the second `in_array` then i think it should be `if (in_array ($key,$keys))` instead of `if (in_array ($key,$vals))` how can the value of the csv equal to key

Comment: i tried with $keys same output displayed. i use val because the $key contains column headers like ID,Name etc. $keys contains db column names. i added the output of that in my question. i need to check smethg lyk this `in_array("ID",Array ( [0] => ID [1] => id)`.am i right na?

Comment: @Nouphal.M: hi friend... this is not about allowed file type. in_array is done between $key and $csv_titles 's array values.

Comment: @barbieegal no you can't use the values like Array ( [0] => ID [1] => id)

Comment: you will have to use if (in_array("ID", Array ('ID','id')) )

Comment: Array("ID","id") is already inserted in $csv_titles and that is taken as $vals in the foreach. so both are same na?

Comment: if it is being used in foreach then it is no longer an array,it became a value. what does   `echo '<br/>'.$keys;` `echo '<br/>';` `print_r($vals);` output?

Comment: i've added that in my question now.please check that

Comment: how can eemail_patient_id be equal to id or eemail_name_sub equal to name, there fore its not coming inside the in_array

Comment: try using `$csv_titles[$keys][0]` it should output id, then you can match it with the `$vals`

Comment: anamika we are not checking eemail_patient_id with id. please carefully not the varibale name. its $key and $vals. not $keys and $vals. i'm checking $key which contains the value ""ID,Name,Email,Mobile,Age,Gender".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you execute "echo $key;" you got "ID Name Mobile Email Age Gender".It' a string.So in_array ($key,$vals) never return true .Because $vals doesnot match with "ID Name Mobile Email Age Gender" string.Thats your actual mistake.please explode $key and the use in_array() function :)

Comment: but how can i explode that? when i tried ` print_r(explode(' ',$key));` it outputs `Array ( [0] => ID Name Mobile Email Age Gender ) `

Comment: what is the print result of $key and $keys ?

Comment: output of $key is i mentioned in the 1st comment. $keys is: email_patient_id eemail_name_sub eemail_mobile_sub eemail_email_sub eemail_age_sub eemail_gender_sub

Comment: ya i have splitted it using preg_split. anyways thanks for pointing out me the mistake.. :)